# Oracle SELECT fails when adding another WHERE condition with INNER JOINs

Tags: sql, oracle

Connecting to an Oracle 12c database with PHP 5.5.29, OCI8 is installed and verified in php info page.

This code works fine and returns all of the matching students

```
SELECT pcs.Student_Number as SNUMBER, pcs.STRING_VALUE as PW, s.GUARDIANEMAIL as GEMAIL, s.WEB_ID as LOGIN, s.FIRST_NAME as FN, s.LAST_NAME as LN, pec.EMAILADDRESS as EMAIL
    FROM PVSIS_CUSTOM_STUDENTS pcs
        INNER JOIN STUDENTS s
          ON pcs.STUDENT_NUMBER = s.STUDENT_NUMBER
        INNER JOIN GuardianStudent gs 
          ON s.DCID = gs.STUDENTSDCID
        INNER JOIN PCAS_EMAILCONTACT pec 
          ON gs.GUARDIANID = pec.EXTERNALIDENT
    WHERE pcs.SCHOOLID=9
          AND pcs.FIELD_NAME='web_password' 
          AND s.ENROLL_STATUS=0
```

However adding another condition to find just one student fails and doesn't seem to return an error, just 0 rows found.  I'm using "12345" as an example, and yes it's a number field so I don't need to quote it.

```
SELECT pcs.Student_Number as SNUMBER, pcs.STRING_VALUE as PW, s.GUARDIANEMAIL as GEMAIL, s.WEB_ID as LOGIN, s.FIRST_NAME as FN, s.LAST_NAME as LN, pec.EMAILADDRESS as EMAIL
    FROM PVSIS_CUSTOM_STUDENTS pcs
        INNER JOIN STUDENTS s
          ON pcs.STUDENT_NUMBER = s.STUDENT_NUMBER
        INNER JOIN GuardianStudent gs 
          ON s.DCID = gs.STUDENTSDCID
        INNER JOIN PCAS_EMAILCONTACT pec 
          ON gs.GUARDIANID = pec.EXTERNALIDENT
    WHERE pcs.SCHOOLID=9
          AND pcs.FIELD_NAME='web_password' 
          AND s.ENROLL_STATUS=0 
          AND s.STUDENT_NUMBER=12345
```

Comment: Let's start with the obvious. So: your table STUDENT has a row with STUDENT_NUMBER = 12345... then PVSIS_CUSTOM_STUDENT has at least one row with the same STUDENT_NUMBER and with SCHOOLID=9?

Comment: Does your first query return student 12345 among the returned rows? I'm guessing not. In any case, the question is not very useful without sample data, results + expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any obvious "faults" with your sql.
However, if student 12345 is missing in any way data from (dcis, studentsdcid, guardianid, externalident, student_number) or there are no matching data in any of the tables. Then no record will be returned since you are using inner joins.

2 suggestions:

*Try changing the inner joins to left joins when you try searching for student 12345. If it returns any data you will then see what might be missing

*Try searching for a student which appear in the list from the first sql statement. If this still does not return any record then you might have to restructure your sql statement

Comment: Interesting, If I do change them to left joins it fails to lookup from the PCAS_EMAILCONTACT table which indeed doesn't have any data for that student.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably cause no any record matches with those condition in place since it's `AND`. Try making that last condition to a `OR` condition and see like

```
WHERE pcs.SCHOOLID=9
      AND pcs.FIELD_NAME='web_password' 
      AND s.ENROLL_STATUS=0 
      OR s.STUDENT_NUMBER=12345
```

Comment: Brilliant! But will that do what the OP needs? OR has different meaning from AND...

Comment: @mathguy, it's not meant to be a solution rather to let OP know why it stopped getting record. Hope that's pretty obvious from answer. isn't it?

Comment: No... it wasn't obvious. Especially since it makes no sense. The OP said the query did return rows without that additional condition. If you add another condition with OR, it will return at least the rows it returned without that condition at all, so what is the point of trying with the OR?

Comment: What seemed pretty obvious (to me at least) was that the OP wanted to know why he didn't get results with the AND condition. That question makes sense, and is what he asked. I offered a suggestion (similar to yours, more detailed, and before your Answer) in a Comment.

Comment: An OR still returns all of the other records.  I tested it just for giggles.

Answer (score 0):

I am not writing the whole query,just a sample one below
Using OR Condition:

```
SELECT pcs.Student_Number as SNUMBER, pcs.STRING_VALUE as PW,
s.GUARDIANEMAIL as GEMAIL, s.WEB_ID as LOGIN, s.FIRST_NAME as FN,
s.LAST_NAME as LN, pec.EMAILADDRESS as EMAIL
FROM PVSIS_CUSTOM_STUDENTS pcs
    INNER JOIN STUDENTS s
      ON pcs.STUDENT_NUMBER = s.STUDENT_NUMBER
    INNER JOIN GuardianStudent gs 
      ON s.DCID = gs.STUDENTSDCID
    INNER JOIN PCAS_EMAILCONTACT pec 
      ON gs.GUARDIANID = pec.EXTERNALIDENT
WHERE pcs.SCHOOLID=9
      AND pcs.FIELD_NAME='web_password' 
      AND s.ENROLL_STATUS=0 
      AND s.STUDENT_NUMBER=12345
      OR
      <other Student details>
```